# Creating a new instance of the same type as another intsance

Tags: java, eclipse

I'll try to keep my question simple:

I have the following instance:

`MainClass mc = new ExtendingClass()`

I want to create a brand new instance using the reference `mc`.
I've read multiple pages online, but found no suitable answer.

One can assume it would look *something* like this ~ (Perhaps it will help you understand).
`MyClass mc2 = new mc.getBaseClass()`

Basically the outcome should be the same as this:

`MyClass mc2 = ExtendingClass()` But it would allow me to create `mc2` during runtime as it can be an instance of various extending classes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
mc.getClass( ).newInstance( );
```

This of course only works if `ExtendingClass` has a no-arg or default constructor. If you want to handle arguments to the constructor, it gets a tiny bit more complicated (for example, if you have a constructor that takes a `String`):

```
Constructor<ExtendingClass> constructor = mc.getClass( ).getConstructor(String.class);
constructor.newInstance("foo");
```

Comment: welp, this seems to do the trick. But is it possible there is a way that doesn't force me to use the `throw` declaration or surround it with try-catch?

Comment: @Acidic: nope, because there's a need for the runtime to signal errors if (for example) there is no no-arg constructor, or the constructor's private, etc and it needs exceptions to achieve that.

Comment: @Acidic Why are you trying to avoid try-catch? It's a standard and useful construct, and you can't get very far in java without it.

Comment: @Dogmatixed not trying to avoid it specifically, just trying to understand the possible solutions in a more comprehensive way. My question might've come off a bit wrong.

Comment: @Acidic reading my comment now it sounds kind of harsh. I'm sorry, your question was fine.